# C++ ofstream dynamic file names and content

Tags: c++, file, fstream, naming, ofstream

Trying to write a dynamic file name and content using fstream with the following:

```
ofstream file;
    file.open("./tmp/test.txt");
    //file.open("./tmp/%s.txt.txt", this->tinfo.first_name);    //nope file.open->FUBAR
    //file.open("./tmp/" + this->tinfo.first_name + ".txt");    //nope this->FUBAR
    //file.write( "%s\n", this->tinfo.first_name);              //nope this->FUBAR
    file << "%s\n", this->tinfo.first_name;                     //nope %s->FUBAR
    //Me->FUBU
    file << "test\n";
    file << "test\n";
    file.close();
```

I was naive enough to assume the printf (%d, this->foo) conventions will work, if not for the actual file name, then for the content.

Nothing seems to work, what am i missing?

just in case its something in my includes:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
//#include <stdio.h>    //redundant, as "stdafx.h" already includes it
#include <stdlib.h>     /* srand, rand */
#include <time.h>       /* time */

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> 
#include <string>
```

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values instead of using their default constructors and immediately changing them. In this case, that means that `ofstream file; file.open("./tmp/test.txt");` should be `ofstream file("./tmp/test.txt");`. Also, you don't need to call `file.close();`. The object's destructor will do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `%s` this case, the ofstream will implicitly  understand `this->tinfo.first_name`. So please replace this line

```
file << "%s\n", this->tinfo.first_name;                     //nope %s->FUBAR
```

by

```
file << this->tinfo.first_name << "\n";                     //nope %s->FUBAR
```

Answer (score 1):

if `this->tinfo.first_name` is a `std::string` you can append everything into one `string`.

```
std::string temp = "./tmp/" + this->tinfo.first_name + ".txt";
file.open(temp);
```

If not, building a `string` with a `std::stringstream`

```
std::ostringstream temp;
temp << "./tmp/" << this->tinfo.first_name << ".txt";
file.open(temp.str());
```

should handle any data type that `%s` will work with.

[Documentation for std::ostringstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream)

Note: file `open` that can consume a `std::string` was added in C++11. If compiling to an older standard you will need

```
file.open(temp.c_str());
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you would want to use printf syntax with fstream. I would simply suggest using `ofstream` the same way you would use `cout`. E.X:
`file << this->tinfo.first_name << '\n';`